# iPhone App confirm identity to device

Tags: iphone, ios

I work at a museum that offers members access to our museum via an iPhone App.  I'm looking for a way to avoid the member having to also present supplemental identification to confirm they are indeed the member.  I originally thought I could query the phone's number and compare to the phone we have on file, but there is no accepted way to access the phone number directly through the SDK.  Anyone else have a method to pre-validate a app user?  Username/password validation is not what I'm looking for.  I need something that isn't readily dissemanable/shareable.

Comment: Keep in mind that if you have plist in your app it can probably be read by somebody who should not read it. This could raise some privacy issues. Another solution would be to ask server for the information, in your example ask a server if this phone number belongs to a member. One unique token I could think of is MAC address of a device, but I don't see you ask the user for that.

Answer (score 2):

This is what PassKit is designed for.

Comment: Unfortunately Apple won't support 2D barcodes in Passbook so this is a non-starter for us.

Answer (score 0):

You could use email address validation: when you open the app, have the user type in the email address that is associated with their museum account, or ask their permission to look at their address book and figure out what their email address is. When they tap Send, save an entry in a server-side database with a hash of that user’s email address (don’t store the address if you don’t have to!) and a UUID that you generate for that iPhone using [NSUUID](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSUUID_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Then send that user an email to confirm, and when they open the link in the email, mark their entry in the database as having been approved.

That phone will always be able to log on, and the credentials should be transferred to a new phone when they restore from backup.